# How to preserve XHTML attributes case during `ng build`?

Tags: angular, zk

I'm trying to integrate an Angular 12 app into a ZK application.

Here is my index.zhtml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:z="zul" xmlns="native" lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ZK + Angular 12</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <z:div
      apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
      viewModel="@id('vm')@init('com.c4_soft.zk_angular_demo.MyViewModel')"
      validationMessages="@id('vmsgs')">
        ...
        <z:button label="ZK ++" onClick="@command('cmd')"></z:button>
    </z:div>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

My problem (actually, the first one, I anticipate quite a few others):
attributes in "zul" namespace are case sensitive (z:div `viewModel` and z:button `onClick` for instance) but `ng build` transforms it to lower-case.

How to prevent ng build from processing attributes case for xml tags in namespaces it doesn't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am from the ZK side I don't actually know whether there is a compiler flag/switch do disable the automatic lower casing.

I think angular is trying to compile too much here. zhtml/zul-files are ZK specific formats and need to be parsed/executed by ZK's DHtmlLayoutServlet at server side at runtime. If you process these files with `ng build` it looks like this compiler is unaware of ZK's syntax and changes/breaks things according to it's own conventions defaults (internally angular uses the parse5 html parser which [deliberately switches all tag/attribute names to lowercase](https://github.com/inikulin/parse5/issues/116))

Bottom line: you **can't** compile zhtml/zul files with `ng build`.

Instead what can do is to compile your angular application into JS and then include it into the zhtml page using a script tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:z="zul" xmlns="native" lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ZK + Angular 12</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <script src="yourlibs.js"></script>
    <script src="morelibs.js"></script>
    <script>/*script initializing app-root*/</script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <z:div
      apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
      viewModel="@id('vm')@init('com.c4_soft.zk_angular_demo.MyViewModel')"
      validationMessages="@id('vmsgs')">
        ...
        <z:button label="ZK ++" onClick="@command('cmd')"></z:button>
    </z:div>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here a few links to existing integration examples based on angular 2 and 8:

In both cases the JS files are added explicitly to the zhtml/zul files independent of the actual build process.

https://github.com/zkoss-demo/zkangular2/blob/master/src/main/webapp/hero/index.zhtml

https://github.com/zkoss-demo/client-binding-demo-angular/blob/master/src/main/resources/web/hello.zul

The above is for ZK being the *main* application and allows adding nested angular components/pages.

If you want your angular app to be the *main* app then you might look into [zk-embedded](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Integration/ZK_Embedded), which provides a JS api to integrate zul pages into arbitrary html pages ()

Comment: furthermore the angular team are not planning to support XHTML (which would handle namespaces and case sensitivity correctly) https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18044